# Unity Performance Issue in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity

I'm running an up to date 12.04. Been using it since it came out and only since the past week or so I've come into an odd problem.

The Unity launcher is starting to act odd. When I hover over the Firefox icon for example, normally the black tooltip bubble saying Firefox Web Browser will pop up instantly, but lately it won't show at all or will come in showing only half of it. So I have to move my 
mouse away from the icon then back to it and the black tooltip will show like it should.

This happens randomly, most notably when I first log in, but also it happens frequently during normal usage. It can happen when I have a few apps open or none at all. I haven't had this issue until recently, perhaps an up date cause it is my guess. I've tried taking a screenshot of it, but as soon as I press Print Screen it goes back to normal. Any thoughts on this issue?

I'm using an Asus u56e 6GB memory w 2.4GHz intel core duo with 12.04 32-bit
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was caused after I tweaked some settings using `Compiz Config Settings Manager`. However, it didn't happen very often so I didn't do anything to resolve it.

You can try to reset `Unity` using the following command, however it will set all the unity settings to default:

```
unity --reset
```

OR you can try reinstalling unity:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but the problem still occurs unfortunately. Got a few error messages in the terminal when I tried your methods too, hmm.

Comment: What were the error messages?

Comment: The Update Manger came out with an update for Unity and when I restarted my problem went away, so luckily whatever was in that update helped to fix my problem and now everything is running just as it should!